# How to output SQL results as a list in two columns

Tags: php, forms

What I am trying to do, is create an order form. Currently I have the proper fields populating the form but it looks like this:

```
Choose Item:

 - Item A
 - Item B 
 - Item C
 - Item D
 - Item E
 - Item F
 - Item G
```

I want it to look like this

```
Choose Item:

- Item A   - Item B
- Item C   - Item D
- Item E   - Item F
- Item G
```

I have a table that is creating the first example.

I use a while loop, to create the entries. I do not know how to get it to be in the other format though. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Also if you need more info please ask and I will provide what I can.

This is essentially the code I am using to generate the list:

```
echo "<tr><td bgcolor='CCCCCC'><b>Choose Item:</b></td><td></td></tr>\n";

while (odbc_fetch_row($rsSQL)) {

   $item      = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL, "item"));
   $number    = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL, "number"));

   echo "<tr>\n";
   echo "<td><input type='radio' name='item' value='$number' required>".$item."</td>\n";
   echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

I have multiples of this, as I have items separated by type. And I have the proper  and  tags. Everything works, I just need to figure out how to get it to format properly.

Comment: use css instead of tables, each item should be an element that floats left within a container of appropriate proportions to make it two columns

Comment: i.e. <div id='items'><div class='item'>Item A</div><div class='item'>Item B</div><div class='item'>Item C</div>...</div>

Comment: riekelt, dianuj: It's killing me, that I can't pick you both as the nswer because both are correct and both were given at the same time.

skrilled: I will definitely look into CSS for the final format for this page. I am currently working on the functionality, and as such I wanted to get a 'basic look' for the page. I did not know you could use CSS for that, but now that I know, I will definitely use that for the final product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
echo "<tr><td bgcolor='CCCCCC'><b>Choose Item:</b></td><td></td></tr>\n";

$i = 1;
echo "<tr>\n";
while (odbc_fetch_row($rsSQL)) {
   if ($i % 2 === 0)
      echo "</tr>\n<tr>\n";

   $item      = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL, "item"));
   $number    = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL, "number"));

   echo "<td><input type='radio' name='item' value='$number' required>".$item."</td>\n";
   $i++;
}
echo "</tr>";
```

What it basically does is insert a  every second row.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
$i=0;
 echo "<tr>";
while (odbc_fetch_row($rsSQL)) {

   $item      = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL, "item"));
   $number    = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL, "number"));
   echo "<td><input type='radio' name='item' value='$number' required>".$item."</td>\n";
$i++;
if($i % 2 == 0 ){
  echo "</tr><tr>";
}

}
echo "</tr>";
```